# Резиновый слайдер изображений для мобильных устройств с поддержкой touch

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать слайдер изображений для  мобильных устройств с поддержкой touch.

Требования:

На экране отображается одно изображение, которое масштабируется в зависимости от размеров устройства и от ориентации устройства (сделано).

Кроме этого, данный слайдер должен поддерживать управление жестами - touch. За раз прокручивается по одному изображению. (не сделано)

Еще должна быть предусмотрена автоматическая прокрутка изображений, которую можно включать/выключать в js.

Под слайдером располагаются элементы управления - круги, которые меняют свой цвет в зависимости от текущего изображения и по клику на которые, слайдер также прокручивается.(набросал структуру)

Вот html и css - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/nRq5G/

Пожалуйста, помогите реализовать это чудо.

**[Начал сочинять](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/nRq5G/3/)**, но к сожалению, пока не получается...

Comment: Первая же ссылка в [Google](http://wowslider.com/ru/jquery-slider-pinboard-fly-demo.html)...
Запрос был "jquery banner slider". На моём Asus Tf300T вроде как крутится, хоть и тяжеловато, для мобильных устройств явно придётся что-то подправить... Можно, конечно, поискать совсем готовое решение, если сама цель именно взять готовое и не заморачиваться.

Comment: Вам подойдет > http://fotorama.io/ [Масштабируемость](http://fotorama.io/customize/dimensions/), [свайп-контроль](http://fotorama.io/customize/arrows-click-swipe/), [автопрокрутка](http://fotorama.io/customize/autoplay/), [круги](http://fotorama.io/customize/captions/)

Comment: [Owl карусель](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) или [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - обе использовал множество раз, среди demo у обеих каруселей найдёшь именно то, что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сделать ванильным жс, есть события touchstart touchend, берете координаты для свайпа, процентов 10% слева и 10% справа и детектите эту область
[Ссылка на тач события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

[Ссылка на координаты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)